# vim won't download spell file, netrw?

Tags: linux, vim

I got a new laptop with Debian 10 and moved my `.vimrc` file from my old one (Linux Mint).

When I run vim, it says

```
Warning: Cannot find word list "de.utf-8.spl" or "de.ascii.spl"
```

so far so usual, but typing `:set spell` inside of vim gives me:

```
:set spell
Cannot find spell file for "de" in utf-8
Do you want me to try downloading it?

Downloading de.utf-8.spl...
shell returned 127
**error** (netrw) /bin/bash: ftp: command not found
**warning** (netrw) file </tmp/v3pJNib/0.spl> not readable
Could not find it, trying de.ascii.spl...
shell returned 127
**error** (netrw) /bin/bash: ftp: command not found
**warning** (netrw) file </tmp/v3pJNib/0.spl> not readable
Sorry, downloading failed
Warning: Cannot find word list "de.utf-8.spl" or "de.ascii.spl"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I have no idea what's going wrong there. I used this .vimrc-file for years.

Comment: it is missing an `ftp` command to download. Try setting `let g:netrw_ftp_cmd=...` to some binary that can handle ftp or alternatively try to set the `let g:spellfile_URL` to use the `http` protocol. See `:h netrw`  and `:h spellfile.vim` for both plugins.